# API: Music recommendation on Spotify based on tweets, is word2vec or doc2vec required?

Tags: javascript, python, php, api

I want to design a recommendation system that recommends user songs based on their tweets that use the hashtag #nowplaying. Initially, I wanted to weigh down their tweets and analyze word by word and see if they've tweeted anything ABOUT certain songs, but it seems like that will be taking more time for me. Since I won't be analyzing each tweet, but rather just looking up for tweets that contain the hashtag, do I still need to use word2vec or doc2vec in this case?

Just for reference, I will provide a brief idea of the system below. Feel free to comment or give your thoughts on them.

1. User will give access to their Spotify account using the API.
2. Prompt user to log in or if the account is public, they can just input their Twitter username.
3. Twitter's API will run a search for #nowplaying on their account (tweets). For now, the timespan will be from 90 days until the most recent tweet. (I read on Twitter API that I can only do a search for tweets within 7 days if I don't use the premium, is this correct? But I also found a github respo that allows me to do more than 7 days)
4. Analyze the tweet that has the hashtag and extract the song title from the tweets and pass the data to Spotify API to analyze.
5. Find the extracted song on Spotify using the Spotify API.
6. Based on that song, the API will provide 10-20 songs related to be
   compiled into a playlist for the user.
7. Once the songs have been compiled into a playlist, the system will
   show the user the song recommendations, and the user will have the
   option to save it to their account or discard it.

I have close to zero experience working with API, but I have some experience working with few languages like Java, Python.