# PYTHON Tensorflow, Text analyzing: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file

Tags: python, api, tensorflow, nlp

I have the most basic knowledge with Python and working on tweets analyzing API. I found a NLP [tutorial](https://blog.f-secure.com/nlp-analysis-of-tweets-using-word2vec-and-t-sne/) where it uses T-SNE and word2vec. [Reference to my system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65066003/api-music-recommendation-on-spotify-based-on-tweets-is-word2vec-or-doc2vec-req/) posted on Stackoverflow before.

I followed the [tutorial](https://blog.f-secure.com/nlp-analysis-of-tweets-using-word2vec-and-t-sne/) step-by-step, but upon running the code, I encountered an error:

```
Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file
```

Is there a reason to this? Code snippet is as below.

```
def process_raw_data(input_file):
  valid = u"0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ#@.:/ äöåÄÖÅ"
  url_match = "(https?:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z\-\_]+\.[\-\_0-9a-zA-Z]+\.?[0-9a-zA-Z\-\_]*\/?.*)"
  name_match = "\@[\_0-9a-zA-Z]+\:?"
  lines = []
  print("Loading raw data from: " + input_file)
  if os.path.exists(input_file):
    with io.open(input_file, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
      lines = f.readlines()
  num_lines = len(lines)
  ret = []
  for count, text in enumerate(lines):
    if count % 50 == 0:
      print_progress(count, num_lines)
    text = re.sub(url_match, u"", text)
    text = re.sub(name_match, u"", text)
    text = re.sub("\&amp\;?", u"", text)
    text = re.sub("[\:\.]{1,}$", u"", text)
    text = re.sub("^RT\:?", u"", text)
    text = u''.join(x for x in text if x in valid)
    text = text.strip()
    if len(text.split()) > 5:
      if text not in ret:
        ret.append(text)
  return ret
```

Comment: We can't know the encoding of a file whose contents you are not showing. 
 See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors

Answer (score 1):

Your `input_file` probably has different encoding (not utf-8).