# Is there a way to extract a csv file and turning it into vector graphs/values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vector, spotify, word-embedding

I found a [Spotify songs data catalog](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-01-21/spotify_songs.csv) on Github and it's in CSV format. I would like to show the data into a vector space and be able to give each song a vector value of its own. In detail, I would like to give the title of the song a vector value, so I could use it to compare to a query a user made on my website. Eg:

```
Song title: Hey Jude
Artist name: The Beatles
Vector value: 9.0203, 1.10288, 5.277, 3.998
```

Then for user input,

```
Query input: Hey Jude by The Beatles
Vector value: 10.0227, 1.10428, 5.367, 3.970 (obtained using word2vec)
```

The two vectors will have the same dimensions. Is there a way for me to achieve this or is my approach wrong?

Comment: Why not use the [Spotify API](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/) itself?

Comment: I would love to and have actually tried just by using Spotify API, but I came across some issues: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65066003/9060608 Within the query gained from user, I will encounter stopwords, and those needs to be extracted first. I will then turn them into vector values and use that to compare to Spotify's dataset vector values